# Does MACsec (IEEE 802.1AE) support multicast / broadcast?

Tags: ethernet, security, mac

In general, Ethernet supports both multicast and broadcast. However, once you start encrypting the payload, you need a key management. I am wondering if IEEE  802.1AE supports multicast and broadcast? In that case how does MACsec handle the key management?

[This webpage](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/topic-map/understanding_media_access_control_security_qfx_ex.html) states that "MACsec provides point-to-point security". Does this mean only unicast is supported?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MACsec provides security on the point-to-point *link* level. MACsec and 802.1X sit (more or less) in between the physical layer (L1) and the data link layer (L2). The key management is between the layer-1 (point-to-point) link partners, usually a host and its uplink switch port, not between (possibly more distant) layer-2 nodes.

MACsec doesn't impact layer-2 functionality which broadcast & multicast are part of - these still work, of course.

Comment: In other words, multicast and broadcast are still possible. Okay, each link is secured. If a switch receives a MACsec secured multicast Ethernet frame, does it replicate it for all node in the group? I suppose each node has its own link to the switch and therefore uses an individual key.

Comment: Yes. Multicast forwarding takes place regardless of port security. And yes, each link is individually encrypted between switch and host.